# Eigenvalues of matrix with linear dependent rows

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, control-theory

Why is it that, if a matrix has a linear dependent row, e.g.:
$$
A=\begin {pmatrix} 1 \ 2 \\ 2 \ 4 \end {pmatrix},
$$
at least one eigenvalue is zero?

Comment: Because the determinant is zero and $ab=0 \implies a=0 \text{ or } b=0$.

Comment: if you downvoted my answer, well, it is your right, but if you think i downvoted your question let me tell you that i don't downvote under any circumstance

Comment: Nope, I didn't downvote your answer, because you tried to help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found an answer with the help of Bye_World's comment and want to provide it in case anybody else is also wondering: In order to find eigenvalues of a matrix, we need its characteristic polynomial, which is calculated as follows:
$$
\det (\lambda I-A)=\det \begin {pmatrix} \lambda -a_{11} & -a_{12} \\ -a_{21} & \lambda -a_{22} \end{pmatrix}=\lambda ^2 - (a_{11}+a_{22}) \lambda + a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}=0,
$$
where
$$
\det (A)= a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}.
$$
So we can see that if $det (A)=0$, which is the case if there is a linear dependent row, then $\lambda=0$ is a solution.

Comment: The constant term is the value of the characteristic polynomial when $\lambda=0$, which will always be the determinant (or the determinant with a minus sign depending on convention).

Comment: The point of my previous comment is that this is general (not specific to 2D).

Answer (score 0):

If λ=0, then A=A-λI, and det(A)=det(A-λI).

There's a linear dependent row (as you said) in A, and that implies that det(A)=0. But det(A)=det(A-λI), so det(A-λI)=0, and λ=0 is an eigenvalue of A.